# Running simple python app with endless loop on openshift

Tags: python, openshift, telegram-bot

I'm writing small & simple telegram bot on python. I never used this language in my work and decided that's a good way to learn by practice.

To get updates my app currently uses long polling called from an endless loop.

So I'm basically searching for the *simplest* way to run this app on openshift. I tried to use [this](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/777) example on flask but it didn't work. There are a lot of other options to implement background infinite processes with multiprocessing (from django and cerely to tornado) but it seems that all of them are way too advanced and complicated for my rather modest needs.

Comment: This is a bit vague. What do you want the script to do? Do you want it to create a web page? If not, why are you looking at Flask?

Comment: No, that's a point. I don't need to have a web page at all, only a couple of threads constantly communicating with telegram bot api. The problem is that openshift default option for python is wsgi, the second one is flask. And the example above seemed to solve my exact problem in rather simple way. Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: It sounds like you just want a standalone script managed by upstart or supervisord. Unfortunately I don't know enough about Openshift to say how to configure that; I'm sure it will be possible though.

Comment: Why you don't want just to use setWebhook method of Bot API, and forget about polling?

Comment: Telegram API only use https webhooks and you need to use a ssl certificate for that. This option isn't available in free Openshift plans.

Answer (score 3):

If the polling is not event driven, then you could use 'cron' (you can add cron cartridge to your gear) to periodically trigger your python script, that does the work and "dies".

However, keep in mind that Openshfit is not really intended to be your worker thread (unless you are on the bronze plan or higher). Unless you receive an external request to your gear within 24 hour period, your gear will be "idled" and your process will no longer run.

The way to get around this, "officially", is probably to get the bronze plan (you will not be charged unless you require the 4th gear instance),

"Unofficially", you can create a gear with python that will give you a default website. Then you create a new python script that does your job and trigger it using cron. To keep the gear from idling, use something like uptimerobot to ping your "website" every day.

Comment: It's much easier to manage chat sessions etc. when you have constantly running application. That's why I considered cron jobs to be rather inconvenient. So it there a way to achieve that (may be using another (preferably free) platform)? Or this approach is methodologically incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

[How do I get SSL for my domains?](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202535440-How-do-I-get-SSL-for-my-domains-)

> If you are still getting by on OpenShift Online's generous Free plan,
>   you'll see a warning message at the top of your application's SSL
>   configuration area. You can always take advantage of our *.rhcloud.com
>   wildcard certificate in order to securely connect to any application
>   via it's original, OpenShift-provided hostname URL.

Tornado is very simple, my first steps in telegram bot dev I did using this server on openshift platform.